# Java EE JMS Consumer not Receive Message

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms

I'm trying to implement Queue JMS Producer and Consumer with Payara 4. I've created JMS resources inside Payara 4. Below is my JMS connection factory and queue resources

```
jms/testConnectionFactory
jms/testQueue
```

Here is my JMS Sender code

```
@Stateless
public class JMSSender {

    @Inject
    Logger logger;

    @Resource(lookup = "jms/testQueue")
    Queue queue;

    @Inject
    @JMSConnectionFactory("jms/testConnectionFactory")
    JMSContext jmsContext;

    public void createPerson(Person person) {
        this.logger.log(Level.INFO, "Start to send message into JMS Queue");

        this.logger.log(Level.INFO, "Create Person: " + person.toString());

        jmsContext.createProducer().send(queue, person);

        this.logger.log(Level.INFO, "Finish send message to JMS Queue");
    }
}
```

Then here is my JMS receiver code

```
public class JMSReceiver {

    @Inject
    Logger logger;

    @Resource(lookup = "jms/testQueue")
    Queue queue;

    @Inject
    @JMSConnectionFactory("jms/testConnectionFactory")
    JMSContext jmsContext;

    public void receiveMessage() {
        this.logger.log(Level.INFO, "Start to receive message from JMS Queue");

        try {
            JMSConsumer receiver = jmsContext.createConsumer(queue);
            Person person = receiver.receiveBody(Person.class, 1000);

            this.logger.log(Level.INFO, person.toString());
        } catch(JMSRuntimeException e) {
            this.logger.log(Level.WARNING, e.getMessage());
        }

        this.logger.log(Level.INFO, "End receive message from JMS Queue");
    }
}
```

The problem is, I couldn't get the message using my `JMSReceiver` code above and there is no error. I've tried using *Message Driveb Bean* (MDB) and it's work.
I'm new to JMS and I can't figure what's wrong with my `JMSReceiver` code that made it can't receive the message?